# Style Iterated State Array Items in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am iterating through an array of objects. I want my title and type to be in the same div, but on different lines. For instance:

**Clean**

**Housekeeping**

Currently, I have something like: **Clean** **Housekeeping**

How can I change my css to achieve this. Here's my code:

```
todolist.jsx
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./TodoList.scss";

const TodoList = ({ todos = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <ul>
          <li className="todo-list" key={todo.id}>
            {todo.title}
            {todo.type}
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default TodoList;
```

```
TodoList.scss
```

```
.todo-list {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: did you try to add `</br>` between `{todo.title} and {todo.type}` ?

Comment: You can put each value on a ``<li>`` like ``<li>{todo.title}</li> <li>{todo.type}</li>``

Comment: The `key` here is pointless as it's the `<ul>` that is repeated. If both items should be in the same `<li>` the correct accessible way to have them on different lines (if I understand the semantics correctly) is to have each of them in a separate `<p>`.

Comment: @MiguelHidalgo this actually separates them. But when I submit a new task, instead of placing it on a new div, it places it right next to the old one. Side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add `<p>`s inside the `<li>` for each attribute of todo:

```
export default function App() {

 const todos = [{title: 'title1', type: 'type1'}, {title: 'title2', type: 'type2'}]

  return (
    <div>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
        <ul key={todo.id}>
          <li className="todo-list">
            <p>{todo.title}</p>
            <p>{todo.type}</p>
          </li>  
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Change `display: flex` to `display: block`:

```
.todo-list {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

[image]

Comment: this actually separates them. But when I submit a new task, instead of placing it on a new div, below the existing title and type, it places it right next to the old one. Side by side.

Comment: Would this happen if you commented out the css?

Comment: Works well without the css, but I need each submitted title and type to be visibly distinct with something like border-radius